# Can you explain to me the difference between two programs?

Tags: c, memory-management

Program to see memory allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *p;
    printf("the address of p is = %u\n",p);
}
```

What is the difference

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *p;
    printf("the address of p is = %u\n",&p);
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to print pointers with `%u` (undefined behavior, anything can happen). You *must* use `printf ("%p\n", (void *)foo);`

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first program prints the value of the uninitialized pointer p interpreted as an unsigned integer.   Since the pointer is not initialized the value printed is whatever value happens to be in that location.
The second program prints the address of the pointer p interpreted as an unsigned integer.  While not technically legal, it will work on most systems where the sizeof(char *) == sizeof(unsigned int).    Since the variable "p" is an automatic variable you will get a value in the address range that your runtime assigns to the C stack.

Edit: to clarify from the comments.   Printf formats the data passed to it in parameters according to the control string.   %u means to print an unsigned integer.   So when you pass in `p`, C passes in the value of the pointer variable to printf.   The # of bytes passed in depends on the sizeof(pointer) for that platform.   printf generally only "works" when the types of the data passed in as parameters after the control string matches all of the %-directives in the control string.   But in cases where the sizeof(onetype) == sizeof(another-type), what I wrote is correct: printf will interpret the bits in a particular parameter position as being of the type specified in the corresponding location in the control string.   And where sizeof(pointer) == sizeof(unsigned int), what you will get is the value of the pointer printed out as an unsigned int.

Comment: "Since the pointer is not initialized the value printed is whatever value happens to be in that location" - nope, no one dereferences the poiner in the first example.

Comment: You can't guarantee that the program will print a `p` *interpreted as an unsigned integer*. It may be the case, it may not.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think he meant the location of the pointer, not the location the pointer points to.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, Cubic is correct.   Whatever is stored in the memory location where the pointer is allocated will be printed.    You misinterpreted what I wrote

Comment: @dreamlax Yes the details are more involved.   What will happen in most systems is that the printf routine will evaluate the data in the location of the parameter.   Because the %u directive is used, it will interpret the data as an unsigned int.    The actual data output depends on the size of pointer versus sizeof unsigned int, which I clearly point out in my answer.

Comment: @Bogatyr: The C standard makes no guarantee of that behaviour though. This may be the behaviour on some systems simply because the hardware allows it, but it is stated in the C standard that providing the wrong type for the format specifier is undefined behaviour. See section §7.19.6.1 paragraph 9, which states: *If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.* Note that this doesn't mention anything about reinterpreting data, it simply states that the behaviour is undefined, so there is no guarantee what will happen.

Comment: @dreamlax Yes of course there is a difference between standard behavior and typical behavior on typical platforms.  On today's mainstream platforms there is only a flat global memory space, so you can expect what I said to be true.   However, in languages like OpenCL you get physically separate address spaces and you would truly get garbage when mixing up the types there.

Answer (score 1):

The first program prints garbage due to **undefined behavior** using an uninitialized automatic variable (p) and using a printf format specifier not matching the argument (unsigned int versus pointer-to-object).
The second one prints the address of p (but technically invokes undefined behavior as well).

Comment: The first one doesn't invoke UB because of the uninitialized variable. Using the value of `p` is legal (as long as you don't dereference it), it just has indeterminate value. In both cases, the UB arises out of using `%u` for printing a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 In what way is passing p to printf for formatting not *using* it? p is a pointer with an indeterminate value and its value is used within printf. Here the pointer is used, not what it points to. This is no different from `int i; printf ("%d", i);` just with pointers.

Comment: @Jens Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying. To quote myself: "Using the value of p is legal (as long as you don't dereference it), it just has indeterminate value."

Comment: @H2CO3 That's wrong. Dereferencing doesn't even enter the picture. p may contain a trap representation (C99 3.17.2) and passing it as an argument or even assigning it to another object is undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3 Using an indeterminate value is undefined behavior. Assuming the downvote was yours, would you please reconsider?

Comment: This I have to agree with, I was fairly certain that it is UB to use an indeterminate value.

Comment: @Jens The downvote isn't mine. [Screenie.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/13oldlfqa42t503/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-09%20at%203.54.56%20PM.png) (But then at that time why did they keep telling me that it isn't UB? 'Tis screwed up, eh...)

Answer (score 0):

You have the pointer variable allocated at one memory address while the variable it points to at another.

```
     +---+                +-------------------+
     | p | -------------> |     variable      |
     +---+                +-------------------+
 Address: 0xBBBBBBBB     Address: 0xAAAAAAAA
```

You could have a code like this:

```
int a = 5;
int* p = &a; // p, located at 0xBBBBBBBB will point to a, located at 0xAAAAAAAA
```

Printing the address of a variable returns you just the 0x(stuff).

& < variable> = address which your variable is located at, whether it is a variable or a pointer (which is a variable its own)